# Dropdown menu bug

Tags: bug, android-app

When I browse on any Stack Exchange site on the app and select the dropdown menu, (questions, tags, etc) it goes out way out of the proportion.

Here is a screenshot of the app reproducing the bug:

[image: Android dropdown menu]

Does anyone get this bug as well too?

System Specs:

Moto G

Android 4.4.4

Stack Exchange 1.0.71

Comment: Welcome to SE! What version of the app are you using? Also, what type of device, including the operating system?

Comment: I am using Moto G (1st Gen) under Android 4.4.4 and latest version of SE.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not an expert here, so I apologize for not being the one who can help you. I just asked because generally with bug reports, that information is useful. I'm sure someone will come along soon to give you assistance!

Comment: "latest version of SE" won't be true once the next version comes out. Better to actually state what the precise version is. That can be found by going to the hamburger menu and choosing "About".

Comment: Updated question with system info.